# Connection between private azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

I have created 2 app services A,B with private endpoints in the same vnet. I want to call service b from service a.

I have used the same subnet for outbound vnet integration for both. I have also set WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1. Yet I am unable to call service b from service a. What could be a solution?

Comment: Does The private endpoint of both services belong to the same subnet of the Vnet? Otherwise, we need to enable communication between two subnets of VNet. Aslo, look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/503122/is-website-vnet-route-all-redundant-or-soon-to-be.  Seems like the config name is changed to vnetRouteAllEnabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created two App service A, B with private endpoints in the same vnet.

[image]

If you are unable to call service `b` from service `a` it could be due to multiple reasons. Ensure that private DNS zone is required when using private endpoints. Otherwise, the URL for the app service does not resolve correctly to an IP address. Make sure both Service A and Service B are in the same VNet subnet.

Created both App service vnet integration for outbound traffic with different subnet in same vnet like below:

[image]

If you set `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` in the app settings to `1`, all of the outbound calls are affected and if you want to have your app use Azure DNS private zones, you should set `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` with value `168.63.129.16.`

Make sure in your **Private DNS zone** -> under setting, virtual network links -> add like below:

[image]

[image]

Now when I try to call App service `b` from service `a` in kudo console runs App service in private endpoint got successfully like below:

In App service -> under Development Tools, Advanced tools -> select Debug console like below:

[image]

[image]

***References***:

[Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration)

[Connect privately to an App Service apps using private endpoint | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint)